# How to handle a failed future in a for-comprehension

Tags: scala, future, option-type, for-comprehension

i have the following for comprehension. It is supposed to delete a row in my database but only if the row exists (So if there is a news for the given id):

```
override def deleteNews(newsId: Long): Int = {
    val getAndDelete = for {
         Some(news) <- newsDao.get(newsId)// returns Future[Option[News]]
         delete <- newsDao.remove(news)   // returns Future[Int]
     } yield delete
     Await.result(getAndDelete, responseTimeout)
}
```

But i don't know how to handle the case when there is no element for a given id. Currently this exception is thrown:

```
Unexpected exception[NoSuchElementException: Future.filter predicate is not satisfied]
```

I hope my approach is not to awful :D

I'm relatively new to scala.

Comment: what does the return type `Int` denote?

Comment: The rows affected by the query on the db

Comment: Should return `Future[Into]` and compose from there, rather than await

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Await` is not that great of an idea: it's best to delay the blocking as long as you possibly can.

IMO, no element for a given ID shouldn't be a failure.  `newsDao.get` should return a successful future of `None` if there's nothing with that ID, you shouldn't call `newsDao.remove` on an ID which doesn't exist if you can help it, and the overall result should just be successfully deleted zero rows (as I'd look at the contract of `deleteNews` as ensuring that at some point between the call and the return there were no rows associated with `newsId` (a little bit of handwaving here around data races, of course...)).

So with that, assuming you can't change `newsDao`'s implementation:

```
val getFut: Future[Option[News]] =
  newsDao.get(newsId).recover {
    // can still fail for other reasons
    case _: NoSuchElementException => None
  }

// I really prefer map/flatMap directly vs. for-comprehension sugar, especially when dealing with multiple monadicish things

// Not the most succinct, but leaving meaningful names in for documentation
val getAndRemove =
  getFut.flatMap { newsOpt =>
    newsOpt.map { news =>
      newsDao.remove(news)
    }.getOrElse(Future.successful(0))
  }
```

If you still need `deleteNews` to return a bare `Int`, you can `Await.result` and accept that you'll sometimes get exceptions thrown and that this is probably suboptimal.

Comment: And yes, I confess, I'm not sure I'd be able to translate that back to a for-comprehension on the first try.

Answer (score 0):

As Levi mentioned, always try to avoid blocking and when you pattern match, make sure you handle all the cases.

You can do this using for-comprehension like below:

```scala
def deleteNews(newsId: Long): Future[Option[Int]] =
  for {
    news   <- newsDao.get(newsId)
    delete <- Future.sequence(news.map(id => newsDao.remove(id)).toList)
  } yield delete.headOption
```

Honestly I have not used this trick to go from `Option[Future]` to `Future[Option]`. I would be interested to see what others says!